What is the correct way to use a regex pipe in an awk field separator?
Consider the string hello(world).
I wanted to use an awk invocation to extract world.
This was my first attempt, and the output was an empty string, with no errors.
echo 'hello(world)' | awk -F'(|)'  '{print $2}'

My second attempt was to use character classes, which produced the expected behavior:
echo 'hello(world)' | awk -F'[()]' '{print $2}'

However, given that awk's documentation claims that the field separator can be a regular expression, I expected the first attempt to work.
Here is my awk version:
$ awk --version
GNU Awk 5.0.1, API: 2.0 (GNU MPFR 4.0.2, GNU MP 6.2.0)
Copyright (C) 1989, 1991-2019 Free Software Foundation.

Why does the expression (|) not achieve the desired result?

The section that states FS (including -F) is a regexp is 4.5.2 not 4.5.5, and it links that term to section 3 on awk regexps which includes 3.3 on (awk) regexp operators showing ( ) as regexp operators, and explaining why only the left parenthesis needs to be backslashed.

The regexp (|) means the same as |, the ( and ) just put it in a group unnecessarily. The ( and ) regexp grouping metachars are useful for writing regexps like (a|b)c to say that c can be preceded by either a or b, or for cases where you need capture groups to backreference later, but not here.
If you don't want ( and ) to be treated as regexp metachars then you need to escape the opening (, and only the opening (, because the closing ) is only a regexp metachar if it follows an opening unescaped (, just like ] is only a regexp metachar if it follows an opening unescaped [. If you choose to also escape the ) or ] that's technically undefined behavior per POSIX, just like escaping any other literal character is, though I've never personally come across an awk variant that wouldn't just treat it as a literal character.
Just like when you write a dynamic regexp, when you write a Field Separator string, it undergoes 2 phases of parsing, first when the string is converted to a regexp/field separator where you define it, then again when it is used as such during execution of the code. Given that, if you want to use \ to escape the metachars in a FS, you need to escape them twice, i.e. \\. Alternatively, instead of putting 2 backslashes before the metachar you could put it inside a bracket expression [...] and that would also make it literal. IMO doing the latter makes your code clearer than doubling escapes plus [)] doesn't have the minor problem that \\) is technically undefined behavior if you decided to "escape" both chars.
So, to make ( and ) literal you can write either of these in any awk:

awk -F'\\(|)' '{print $2}'
awk -F'[(]|)' '{print $2}'
awk -F'[()]' '{print $2}'

with my preference FWIW being #3, even though the ) is literal inside or outside of the bracket expression, as it's more concise than the first 2 alternatives.

After fiddling around with putting \ in front of various characters, I finally realized that the problem was with the () and not with the | character. Moreover, the () needed to be double-escaped.
The following expression achieves the desired result:
echo 'hello(world)' | awk -F'\\(|\\)'  '{print $2}'
world

Curiously, it omitting the escape on the closing parenthesis also appears to work correctly:
echo 'hello(world)' | awk -F'\\(|)'  '{print $2}'
world



Why does the expression (|) not achieve the desired result?

From Regexp Operators in awk

The left or opening parenthesis is always a metacharacter; to match
one literally, precede it with a backslash. However, the right or
closing parenthesis is only special when paired with a left
parenthesis; an unpaired right parenthesis is (silently) treated as a
regular character.

taking this into account you might get desired effect by writing
echo 'hello(world)' | awk -F')|\\('  '{print $2}'

